# How to print multiple rows using sub query?

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, multiple-records

I am new in php. I have a code in which i try to print multiple rows using sub query

```
<?php
include ("connection.php");

$q_opinion="SELECT r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as opinion, r.notification_date, t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle, s.title as stitle, pr.opinion_id, pc.id, pr.client_id as pr_client, pc.address, pc.liaison_one, city.id, pc.head_office_id, city.city, pc.title as cname
FROM og_ratings r 
LEFT JOIN og_companies c
ON r.client_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t
ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN og_actions a
ON r.pacra_action = a.id
LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o
ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
LEFT JOIN og_lterms l
ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
LEFT JOIN og_sterms s
ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
LEFT JOIN pacra_client_opinion_relations pr
ON pr.opinion_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN pacra_clients pc
ON pc.id = pr.client_id
LEFT JOIN city
ON city.id = pc.head_office_id
WHERE r.client_id  = (SELECT opinion_id FROM pacra_client_opinion_relations WHERE client_id = 50)
";
$result = mysql_query($q_opinion) or die;
$rating = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $rating[] = $row['cname'];
  $action[] = $row['atitle'];
  $opinion[] = $row['opinion'];
}
for ($i=0; $i<count($rating); $i++)
{ ?>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
         <td><?= $rating[$i] ?> </td>
         <td><?= $action[$i] ?> </td>
         <td><?= $opinion[$i] ?> </td>

    </tr>
    </table>
<?php   
}
?>
```

This code show me blank result in my php file. But when i run this query in PhpMyadmin it show me error that it contain `more than one line`

if i change my subquery with `limit`

like

`SELECT opinion_id FROM pacra_client_opinion_relations WHERE client_id = 50 LIMIT 1`

Then it print record

But `id =50` contain 4 records.

I want to print all record mean want to print multiple rows. How i can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r.client_id = (your sub query)
```

When doing this, the query is trying to match the ID with **one** piece of data from the sub query. However, as you've mentioned, this query returns four pieces of data. So you want to check if the ID is IN the subquery data, not equal to it.

```
r.client_id IN (your sub query)
```

The reason your query worked when you added `LIMIT 1` is because your sub query was only returning one piece of data, as expected.

Take a look here for more information on the IN clause:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm